# format( ) function not not evaluating in Terraform template file within "for" directive

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, ansible-inventory, terraform-template-file

First a little context to question, so maybe someone can redirect me to correct answer/post. I have been learning Terraform for a few days, and now want to generate an "ansible inventory" as I deploy my tf files.

After lot of beginner searching I found data "template_file" is heavy to beginner like me, but I could SO-Frankenstein-monster my way to:

```
resource "local_file" "inventory" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/hosts.tpl",
    {
      master        = aws_instance.master.*.public_ip
      nodes_ubuntu  = aws_instance.node.*.public_ip
     }
  )
  filename = "./inventory"
}
```

With a template file formatted like:

```
[master]
%{ for ip in master ~}
control ansible_host=${ip}
%{ endfor ~}

[nodes_ubuntu]

%{ for ip in nodes_ubuntu ~}

$${format{"withCurly-%02d",index + 1}} ansible_host=${ip}

$${format("WithRound-%02d",index + 1)} ansible_host=${ip}

format("PureFormat-%02s",index+1) ansible_host=${ip}

#These are possible combinations I used and failed for format()

%{ endfor ~}
```

Which results in confusing:

```
[master]
control ansible_host=ip.add.re.ss

[nodes_ubuntu]

${format{"withCurly-%02d",index + 1}} ansible_host=ip.add.re.ss

${format("WithRound-%02d",index + 1)} ansible_host=ip.add.re.ss

format("PureFormat-%02s",index+1) ansible_host=ip.add.re.ss
```

while,

```
${format("WithRound-%02d",index + 1)} ansible_host=${ip}
```

Generates error
`Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "index"`

I was expecting it to be something like:

```
[nodes_ubuntu]
ubuntu-01 ansible_host= ip.add.re.ss
```

How can I correct the code, or is it Terraform bug, since I saw SIMILAR code worked but forgot to note down reference.

Comment: So where would you expect index to come from?

Comment: @marko I guess from `nodes_ubuntu  = aws_instance.node.*.public_ip` from here?

Comment: Nope, any variables that you want to use inside of the template and that are not defined will throw such an error.

Comment: So how do i go about to reach the end goal?  tbh I am new to this and small things stump me.
`${format("WithRound-%02d",index + 1)} ansible_host=${ip}`  I removed this and the whole thing is printed as is. I am very confused.. IP are iterating ok and i get Ip/count i.e 2 ip for 2 instances. Just the label (hostname) is messed up.

Comment: Try with removing the first occurrence of `%{ endfor ~}` because you now have two and one is not needed. Maybe the index will work then.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to type in, `%{ for ip in nodes_ubuntu ~}` loop initiator. Corrected now.

Comment: I'd say that the one that's least likely to work is this one: `$${format{"withCurly-%02d",index + 1}} ansible_host=${ip}`. If you look at the `format` function specification, it's with regular brackets: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format. What I am also not sure about is usage of Terraform built-in functions inside of the `templatefile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result you described, where the function calls remained in the output, is because you used `$${` to escape the normal `${` template interpolation sequence, asking Terraform to insert a literal `${` instead. That would be an appropriate thing to do if you were generating source code for another language which uses `${` to mean something itself, but since you want Terraform to evaluate that interpolation you must use the non-escaped `${` form, as you tried in your second case.

The problem you saw when you fixed the incorrect escaping is that you haven't declared any symbol `index` either in the call to `templatefile` or locally within the template.

If your goal is to use the index of each element of `nodes_ubuntu` then you can achieve that by declaring a second symbol in the `for` directive. If you give two symbols then the first one represents the key/index while the second one represents the value:

```
%{ for index, ip in nodes_ubuntu ~}
${format("WithRound-%02d", index + 1)} ansible_host=${ip}
%{ endfor ~}
```

---

This is a valid way to work with a list of resource objects declared using `count`, but before adopting this strategy be sure to consider how this will behave under future maintenance: Terraform is tracking these objects by their index in the count, and so if you increase the resource `count` later that'll add a new index to the end. If you *decrease* `count` then you'll always remove entries from the end of this list. If you replace any one of the hosts then the corresponding index will have its IP address change in this template result.

Those restrictions are just fine if these multiple virtual machines are more like "cattle" than "pets", which is to say that if you need to destroy one of them they are all equally viable to destroy. It's not a good design if any of them have unique characteristics that might cause you to want to specifically destroy one in the middle of the list.

In your case it looks like this will be appropriate, because you've already distinguished the "master" and "node" roles in separate resources and so the nodes are hopefully all fungible. I mention it only because it's a relatively common gotcha to write a Terraform config which implies that instances are fungible when they actually aren't, which can cause maintenance problems later.

(More information in [When to Use `for_each` Instead of `count`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count#when-to-use-for_each-instead-of-count).)

Comment: This worked wonderfully. And yes those nodes are there to be "lab rats" as I practice on them and all nodes get destroyed. That was beautifully explained. Thank you so much Martin. This explanation should be in terraforms docs, it will save a lot of time for new ones like me.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked out. Unfortunately it's typically the case that it's easier to give a good explanation when there is a concrete non-working example which I can "correct", vs. the documentation which can assume nothing about the reader's intent or what they might've tried already. I do try to incorporate answers I give regularly into the docs (I'm one of the docs contributors) but it often takes a few instances of the same question to get a good sense of how to answer it in a more general way that would be appropriate for that context.

Comment: That dilemma I do understand. That's why I took risk making question long and included as much info as possible, should anyone land here, will be crystal clear about the approach. This shall help someone save a day :)