# How to have Terraform fill in a template file, copy the file to a remote host and set permissions?

Tags: terraform

I have an ini file for a Systemd service I am making. Some of the values in the ini file are Terraform variables or outputs. Is it possible to have Terraform fill in these values, copy to the remote host, and then set the appropriate permissions?

I've looked into template_file function, but it's not clear if this file can be copied to the remote host.

https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile

Comment: Can you show your TF code and explain what it does not work? Any errors?

Comment: Templatefile function does exactly what it is supposed to do: create a file from a template. For any other stuff there are provisioners, but as Marcin mentioned, without the code we can't tell much.

Answer (score 2):

As marcin said, there isn't much data in your question. But I was stuck in a similar issue, [#71440128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440128/format-function-not-not-evaluating-in-terraform-template-file-within-for-di)

I used "for" in template file to get values from variables,
This file was to generate an inventory,

```
resource "local_file" "hosts" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/example.tpl",
           { 
              somevariable = some.var.declaration.*.attribute
                    .
                    .
                    .
           }
        filename = ".path/../example.ini"
}
```

Following is a part of `example.tpl` template file,

```
%{ for index, j in somevariable ~}
${format("sometext-%02d", index + 1)} variable_value=${j}
%{ endfor ~}
```

this template snippet generates,

```
sometext-01 variable_value=somevalue12345
```

I used simple remote-exec to push the ini file to server/remote-host.
At first glance it seems like similar issue so just suggested this approach. There might be better answers out there.

see if this suits your needs (refer to martin's beautifully explained answer at linked question for more clarity)